# Trigonometry to bounce an object

Tags: c++, user-interface, math, drawing, trigonometry

I need to move an object within a drawing area. The object moves randomly and whenever it hits the walls it makes a pi/2 bouncing. (Like the ball on the 'pong' game)

This was easy using two incremental 'dx' and 'dy', and when it collided with the limits I would just change the proper sign. But on this one I have my object moving through v*cos(theta) = x and v*sin(theta) = y. When it hits the wall I need theta to add pi/2 or subtract pi/2 over itself - so the new theta produces the new direction on (x, y).

But I suspect there must be a way to do this, better than mine. I could just check for each screen limit individually (up, left, right, down) the value of theta and increment/decrement in order to produce that pi/2 bouncing. But this will result in a bunch of `if()` statements and I believe there must be a clever way to achieve this.

My code is

```
    ball.x += ball.vel * cos(ball.theta);
    ball.y += ball.vel * sin(ball.theta);

    if( (ball.x + ball.radius) >= window.width || (ball.x - ball.radius) <= 0
    || (ball.y + ball.radius) >= window.height || (ball.y - ball.radius) <= 0) {
        ball.theta += M_PI / 2;
```

But this is not working well. It does some bounces ok, but at some point (after 4 bounces or so) it fails to bounce the way I need it to.

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct {

    double x;
    double y;
    double theta;
    double vel;
    double dt;

} Ball;
```

where `theta` represents the angle which gives it direction, `dt` is not used yet and `vel` is its velocity which is constant by now.

Is there any way I could do this bouncing using trigonometry in an intelligent way and less cpu effort?

**EDIT: changed addition from degrees to radians.**

But it still behaves badly. It bounces like it is supposed to a few times and for no reason that I can see right now it bounces back and takes the inverse trajectory. (Like it changes 180 degrees at that time)

Comment: If this is C++, then `sin` and `cos` take the angle in radians, not degrees, yet it looks like you're adding 90 when you should be adding pi/2.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy You are right, I changed it but sometimes it still gives me a bouncing back (edited the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems wrong. With vertical collision ball velocity should reflect from vertical axis and with horizontal collision ball velocity should reflect from hor. axis:

```
 if ((ball.x + ball.radius) >= window.width || (ball.x - ball.radius) <= 0)
        ball.theta = M_PI - ball.theta;
  else
     if ((ball.y + ball.radius) >= window.height || (ball.y - ball.radius) <= 0) 
           ball.theta = - ball.theta;
```

Comment: yes, I managed to get it yesterday in paper but was to tired to come here and edit the question, but it's good that you responded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The angle sent to the sin and cos functions needs to be in radians not degrees.

Comment: I changed it and it did better in one direction. But still isn't working properly

Answer (score 0):

If You always do turn on PI/2. When from trigonometric formula for cos() or sin() of sum

```
new_dx = vel*cos(theta + PI/2) = vel * (-sin(theta)) = -old_dy;
new_dy = vel*sin(theta + PI/2) = vel * cos(theta) = old_dx;
```

or

```
new_dx = vel*cos(theta - PI/2) = vel * sin(theta) = old_dy;
new_dy = vel*sin(theta - PI/2) = vel * (-cos(theta)) = -old_dx;
```

But it's more simple using absolute elastic collision and change sign for dx or dy depend of collision direction.